# Does backpropagation of error in multilayer neural network depend on the objective function being optimized?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I know for square error gradient descent is equivalent to back propagation. However, for a general objective function, how can I convince myself that back propagation is equivalent to computing derivatives at every layer.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of back propagation is getting the derivative of the objective function using [auto diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation). I would recommand you to understand auto diff well and not being affected too much by the form of the BP algorithm.

Different objective function would have different gradient. BP is one way of calculating that. So if you objective function changed, the algorithm should also be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's what back propagation does, computing the derivatives according to the train rule.

Back propagation is not specially designed for the square error.
With square error $l=0.5(y-t)^2$, the derivative of the output $\frac{\partial l}{\partial y}=y-t$. If the loss function changes, the corresponding derivatives changes accordingly.

And it is not necessary we use any automatic differentiation tools at all, we can always work out and code the derivatives by hand and check them numerically.